# Kubernetes NFS Deployment with PV, PVC Questions

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, kubernetes-pvc

I want to setup a in-cluster NFS-Server in Kubernetes to provide shares for my pods (nginx webroot etc.).

In theory there should be a persistent volume, a volume claim and the NFS-Server, which, as I understand is a deployment.

To use the PV and PVC I need to assign the NFS-Server's IP-Adress, which I don't know, because it automatically generated when I expose the NFS-Server with a service.

The same problem appears if I want to deploy the nfs-server deployment itself, because I am using the PVC as volumes. But I can't deploy the PV and PVCs without giving them the NFS-Server IP.

I think I am lost, maybe you can help me.

1. PV

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-nfs-pv1
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: "/exports/www"
    server: SERVER_NAME:PORT
```

2. PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-nfs-pv1
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Mi
```

3. NFS-Deployment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: nfs-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: nfs-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nfs-server
          image: gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8
          ports:
            - name: nfs
              containerPort: 2049
            - name: mountd
              containerPort: 20048
            - name: rpcbind
              containerPort: 111
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /exports/www
              name: pv-nfs-pv1
      volumes:
        - name: pv-nfs-pv1
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: pv-nfs-pv1
#            fsType: ext4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You create NFS-server deployment.

2) You expose NFS-server deployment by creating service, say "nfs-server", exposing TCP port 2049 (assuming you use NFSv4).

3) You create PV with the following information:

```
  nfs:
    path: /exports/www
    server: nfs-server
```

4) You create PVC and mount it wherever you need it.

Comment: But the PV needs the IP of the NFS-Server and the Deployment has the PCV as a volumeMount and Volume attached. Both PV and PCV cannot be deployed if the NFS IP is not set in the PV and so the NFS Deployment cannot be deployed. That's my struggle here.

Comment: if you deploy nfs-server and create Service with name "nfs-server", then PV can simply go to hostname "nfs-server". There is no need in using IP addresses in Kubernetes.

Comment: I got that, but still I have a Volume and VolumeMount for pv-nfs-pv1 (which is my PVC) in the deployment. The deployment will fail, because the PV / PVC don't exist at the time of the deployment of the NFS. I think, I got some basics wrong :D


The Deployment "nfs-server" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "pv-nfs-pv1"

Comment: that's why you should create gcePersistentDisk BEFORE you run the deployment.

Comment: Now I got it. I mixed up volumes with disks.

Comment: I just want to use the cluster nfs to provide a pvc for the pods. I actually don't need a gcePersistentDisc. Would be hostPath suitable for that?

Comment: hostPath should be fine as long as instance root disk is big enough and fast enough.